# when i run build react app it gives me blank page with errors 404 (Not Found) in console

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

my problem is that when I run build react project it gives me white pages with errors in the console log I tried adding   "homepage": "." and it didn't work still gives me a blank page I tried to delete the router and it worked fine and the page got rendered but without the navbar and router of course  so I think  The problem is because of the router i need help, please
the project works fine when I use npm start it happens only after building it

index file:

```
import React from "react";
import  ReactDOM  from "react-dom";
import "../src/css/style.css";
import "../src/css/about.css";

import Router from "./Components/Router";

const App =()=>{
return(
    <div> 

<Router/>
```

```
)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

router component :

```
    import { Component } from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter,  Routes, Route}  from "react-router-dom";
    import About from "./About";
    import Product from "./Product"
    import Sp from "./Sp"
    import Contact from "./Contact"
    import Home from "./Home";






    class Router extends Component{
     render(){
      return(

        <BrowserRouter>

        
       <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
       <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
       <Route path="/product" element={<Product/>}/>
       <Route path="/sp" element={<Sp/>}/>
       <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
       </Routes>
       
       </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
}
export default Router
```

errors :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2vlv.png

jsonfile:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouF4D.png][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouF4D.png%5D%5B2%5D)

Comment: After you build it are you serving it up locally? It sort of looks like you are just trying to load the html file directly in the browser.

Comment: i use live server extension and I also tried to deploy it on GitHub gh pages-pages but the same problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

thx the problem is solved i just changed the host service from GitHub to netlify